# How to have 2 different windows side by side in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've struggled a lot to do this but I don't seem to handle it on my own. What I need to have is 2 different windows side by side. It should be pretty easy but I haven't found any relevant post on the web. On the left window I'll have some box2d bodies and joints and on the right one there'll be labels dynamically showing the force applied to each joint on the left window. How do I go about that?

P.S. And something to note: Right now I have a CCLayerPanZoom subclass right to which I need to put my second window. So I also need to scale that down so that they fit to the screen.

Comment: Hey, come on, noone's been answering cocos2d questions lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only a single cocos2d view, you can't have two (or more).

If you want a split-view, you'll just have to display some content on one side, other content on the other side, and perhaps draw a frame on top so that you have two areas.

You will also have to add custom logic to prevent nodes from leaving their respective view area.

If there is a lot of overlap from one side into another, it's fixable. Let's say game objects from the left often reach into the info view on the right. In that case draw a background sprite on the info view side which is drawn above all game view side objects. Then add all nodes on the info view side above the background sprite.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for the reply. I've already understood that there's no way of doing exactly the way I want. Here's how I did it: I put a sprite on the right side of my main layer and my CCLayerPanZoom instance on the left side. Now even if I pan/zoom the left layer, the righther content remains the same.

Comment: Let me ask you for another little help once I've caught you: On the left side I'll have box2D bodies with joints. I need to display reaction force on these joints dynamically on the right so called "window". How would I add/remove CCLabels to the right content (sprite) and change their values on every tick of the physics world (which is on the left side) Should I do this with delegates? If so, could you guide me as to how?Sorry, if it's a bit confused.

Comment: A little correction to my previous comment: I've also set z index to 1000 to the right side content so that it's always visible even when a layer is added.